# TypeError: e.preventDefault is not a function in react

Tags: reactjs

**What my code is doing : **

When sendprops value is signup show signup page with rendering email and confirm password component  and send request to signup api
and same goes for login

Actually I am newbie in React and just started to make a tiny project that is login and signup

my code :

```
const Form = ({ sendprop }) => {
  const [formValue, setFormValue] = useState({
    name: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
    confirmPassword: "",
  });
function onFormChange(e) {
    console.log("target : "+e.target.value);
    setFormValue({ ...formValue, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    console.log(formValue);
  }

  // const chooseFormMethod=(prop)=>{
  //   if(prop==="signup"){
  //       handleSubmit  
  //   }
  // }
  const handleSubmit=async(e,prop)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
    if(prop==="signup"){
      console.log("in handleSubmit")
      if(formValue.password===formValue.confirmPassword){
          console.log("in if")
          const res=await axios.post('http://localhost:8000/signup',{
              ...formValue
          })
          console.log(res);
      }
    }
    else{
      const {email,password}=formValue
      const body={
        email:email,
        password:password
      }
      const res= await axios.post('http://localhost:8000/login',body);
      console.log(res);
    }
  }
;
  return (
    <>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(sendprop)}>
        <div id="input-div">
          {sendprop === "signup" ? <NameInput passState={{formValue,setFormValue}}/> : " "}
          <input
            type={"email"}
            placeholder="E m a i l  A d d r e s s"
            id="email-input"
            className="form-input"
            name="email"
            onChange={onFormChange}
            value={formValue.email}
          />
          <div id="border" className="border-div" />
          <input
            type={"password"}
            placeholder="P a s s w o r d"
            id="password-input"
            className="form-input"
            name="password"
            onChange={onFormChange}
            value={formValue.password}
          />
          <div id="border" className="border-div" />
          {sendprop === "signup" ? <ConfirmPassword passState={{formValue,setFormValue}}/> : " "}
        </div>
        <div id="submit-btn-div">
          <button type={"submit"} id="submit-btn">
            S U B M I T
          </button>
        </div>
        {sendprop === "signup" ? <LoginAccount /> : " "}
        {sendprop !== "signup" ? <CreateAccount /> : " "}
      </form>
    </>
  );
};
export default Form;
```

**Warning and Error :**

```
value :  login
FormHeader.js:5 form header login
react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: Expected `onSubmit` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `object` type.
    at form
    at Form (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:250:5)
    at div
    at div
    at div
    at Mainbox (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:120:5)
    at App (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:35:76)
printWarning @ react-dom.development.js:86
error @ react-dom.development.js:60
warnForInvalidEventListener @ react-dom.development.js:9592
setInitialDOMProperties @ react-dom.development.js:9712
setInitialProperties @ react-dom.development.js:9921
finalizeInitialChildren @ react-dom.development.js:10950
completeWork @ react-dom.development.js:22193
completeUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26596
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26568
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26466
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26434
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26085
flushSyncCallbacks @ react-dom.development.js:12042
flushSync @ react-dom.development.js:26201
legacyCreateRootFromDOMContainer @ react-dom.development.js:29575
legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer @ react-dom.development.js:29601
render @ react-dom.development.js:29685
./src/index.js @ index.js:6
options.factory @ react refresh:6
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:24
(anonymous) @ startup:7
(anonymous) @ startup:7
Mainbox.js:12 value :  signup
FormHeader.js:5 form header signup
react-dom.development.js:86 Warning: Expected `onSubmit` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `object` type.
    at form
    at Form (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:250:5)
    at div
    at div
    at div
    at Mainbox (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:120:5)
    at App (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:35:76)
printWarning @ react-dom.development.js:86
error @ react-dom.development.js:60
warnForInvalidEventListener @ react-dom.development.js:9592
diffProperties @ react-dom.development.js:10100
prepareUpdate @ react-dom.development.js:10977
updateHostComponent$1 @ react-dom.development.js:21786
completeWork @ react-dom.development.js:22155
completeUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26596
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26568
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26466
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26434
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26085
flushSyncCallbacks @ react-dom.development.js:12042
flushPassiveEffectsImpl @ react-dom.development.js:27060
flushPassiveEffects @ react-dom.development.js:26984
(anonymous) @ react-dom.development.js:26769
workLoop @ scheduler.development.js:266
flushWork @ scheduler.development.js:239
performWorkUntilDeadline @ scheduler.development.js:533
Form.js:28 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: e.preventDefault is not a function
    at handleSubmit (Form.js:28:1)
    at Form (Form.js:52:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27426:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:26434:1)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:26085:1)
handleSubmit @ Form.js:28
Form @ Form.js:52
renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:16305
mountIndeterminateComponent @ react-dom.development.js:20074
beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:21587
beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:27426
performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26557
workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26466
renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26434
performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26085
flushSyncCallbacks @ react-dom.development.js:12042
flushSync @ react-dom.development.js:26201
legacyCreateRootFromDOMContainer @ react-dom.development.js:29575
legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer @ react-dom.development.js:29601
render @ react-dom.development.js:29685
./src/index.js @ index.js:6
options.factory @ react refresh:6
__webpack_require__ @ bootstrap:24
(anonymous) @ startup:7
(anonymous) @ startup:7
Form.js:28 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: e.preventDefault is not a function
    at handleSubmit (Form.js:28:1)
    at Form (Form.js:52:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at updateFunctionComponent (react-dom.development.js:19588:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21601:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27426:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:26434:1)
```

Comment: you should not call the handler function, pass the `reference` as `<form onSubmit={(e)=>handleSubmit(e,sendprop)}>` and react calls it when you submit

Answer (score 0):

`<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(sendprop)}>` should be  `<form onSubmit={(e) => handleSubmit(e, sendprop)}>`

The event handlers in react are expecting a function, not a function call like in HTML. When you do `handleSubmit(sendprop)`, you're calling the function and setting the return value as the event handler, In your case, `undefined`.

Also, in your function definition, you're expecting two arguments, where the first one is the event object, you missed passing it to `handleSubmit`.

Comment: whats the difference between you wrote code abt event handler and I wrote ? newbiee please explain little more ?

Comment: @Lord I have commented .... we "should" not call the handler function ourselves "react" calls it when you submit :)

Comment: @Lord the explanation is the second para, let me know what is unclear

Answer (score 0):

First, you call the method in wrong way. If you need to send any arguments you should using arrow function.

```
<form onSubmit={ () => handleSubmit(sendprop) }>
```

Because if you just call `<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(sendprop)}>` it will directly called/executed the method in first render not on submit event.

Second, if you need to send the event you need to pass it on your arrow function.

```
<form onSubmit={ (e) => handleSubmit(e, sendprop) }>
```

And you `handleSubmit` accept 2 arguments but you send only one. You need to aware about it.

Answer (score 0):

handleSubmit(e,sendprop)}

and then

const handleSubmit=async(e,prop)=>{
e.preventDefault();
......
.......

}